NGINX configuration for the built react project
I have a problem with the admin panel deployment, css styles don't work on page load.
I made a react build via npm run build and tagged it to the server, index.html opens fine, the problem is only in the css.
My nginx config file
`events {
}
http {
proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com admin.example.com api.example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /var/www/client; 
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example-ssl.key;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name admin.example.com;

    root /var/www/admin/build; 

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/privkey.pem;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/admin/build/;
        autoindex off;
    }
}

upstream api_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000; 
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://api_backend;
    }

   
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api_backend; 
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure";
    }
}

}
`
What could be the problem?
1. If I put the admin panel in the public folder on my node.js server, everything works and css styles work fine.
2. If I go into https://admin.example.com/ devtouls sources and change any style after the page loads, everything becomes normal.

This was solved by adding mime types to nginx
http {

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types; 
    ...
}

mime.types
types {
    text/html    html htm shtml;
    text/css     css;
    text/xml     xml;
    image/gif    gif;
    image/jpeg   jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript js;
    application/json json;
    application/pdf pdf;
    application/xml xml;
    image/png    png;
    image/svg+xml svg;
    video/mp4    mp4;
}

